# Typescript bigint throwing error: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, biginteger, bigint

I am using a bigint in my typescript package, however I can't seem to get typescript to recognise Bigint.

The following code throws an error:

```
const x: bigint = new BigInt(123)
```

```
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I am using Typescript 4.2.4, installed globally. However, the issue persists if I install it locally.

Comment: The ideal way to use BigInt is const x: bigint = BigInt(123);

Comment: I see, thank you. @MBB